# How to host multiple Expressjs applications on Windows Server 2019?

Tags: node.js, windows, express, server

we have about 10 MEAN stack aplications which we would like to host on our Windows Server 2019.

How to setup server and connect with domain?

Thanks for help!

Comment: How do you intend to put 10 apps on one host?  Each with their own domain?  Each on the same domain with separate top level path?  Each on the same domain on a different port?

Comment: If possible on subdomains. But i don't know how to setup Windows Server for nodejs.